# href="../.." points to the wrong URL

Tags: html

I have always thought a relative URL was relative to the URL in the browser address bar. But today my beliefs were shaken.

In a webpage that has the URL https://localhost:44372/docs/morpher.ru/ws/3/russian/declension/GET I put an href which looks like this:

```html
<a href="../../../response-format/index.md">выбор формата ответа</a>
```

When I click the link, the browser takes me to

https://localhost:44372/response-format/index.md

Whereas I would expect to be taken to

https://localhost:44372/docs/morpher.ru/ws/response-format/index.md

Are my expectations incorrect? What is the relative path really relative to?

[image]

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ducabicegi/1/edit?js,console — your expectation is correct. Maybe you missed a redirect response somewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls may be this will help you

Answer (score 2):

It's likely the case that there is a `<base>` tag.

You can change the relative path base like so:

```
<base href="https://example.com/new-base" />
```

Then, everything is relative to this, rather than what the page URL is.

Comment: You're right. There was a base tag: <base href="/" />. Bloody Razor. Thanks!